# My Pymysql commands have no errors but will not work?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql database that I am currently trying to connect python to.  I have successfully created a table with python but when it comes to inserting data in the table my code does not work.

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
                           host = Admin.Host,
                           user = Admin.User,
                           password= Admin.Password,
                           db = "thesystem"
                          )
a = conn.cursor()
sql ="INSERT INTO `a`(`try`) VALUES ('testing')"

a.execute(sql)
```

I have tried this exact command in the Mysql command Line client and it worked.

```
INSERT INTO `a`(`try`) VALUES ('testing');
```

I have also managed to create a table with this same code. I can't figure out why the code runs successfully but does not work.

Comment: Did you call `conn.commit()` after inserting? By default, pymysql is *not* autocommit.

Comment: It worked I been looking for why this would not work for awhile thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution is that pymysql requires that you call `conn.commit()` after making a change. By default, pymysql is *not* autocommit.

Code example at https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL says:

```
. . .
# connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
# your changes.
connection.commit()
. . .
```